# get count results of the complicated query

Tags: mysql

Lets assume I have this sql query

```
SELECT max(times_viewed) as m, member_id, (select count(viewed_url) from exp_member_page_tracker  where member_id=mpv.member_id)
FROM `exp_member_page_tracker` mpv
group by member_id
```

I need to count all results. I do it on this way

```
SELECT count(member_id) from ( SELECT max(times_viewed) as m, member_id, (select count(viewed_url) from exp_member_page_tracker where member_id=mpv.member_id)
FROM `exp_member_page_tracker` mpv
group by member_id) as m2
```

But I am not sure how that is efficient. Could you please suggest me how can I count results in the best way?

Thanks

Comment: I think if there are say 1 million records, it will select this million records and then count. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your subquery, am I missing something, Isn't this same result with more effiency? 
Tryed at sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a03cf/9

**Yours:**

```
SELECT member_id, max(times_viewed) as max_times_viewed 
, (select count(viewed_url) from exp_member_page_tracker  where member_id=mpv.member_id) as countOfViewedUrl
FROM `exp_member_page_tracker` mpv
group by member_id;
```

**Alternative:**

```
SELECT member_id, max(times_viewed) as max_times_viewed
, count(viewed_url) as countOfViewedUrl
FROM `exp_member_page_tracker` mpv
group by member_id;
```